# Add values from basic array to Set<String>

Tags: java, collections, set

```
  private Set<String> fields = new HashSet<>();

  public void fields(String... s){
    this.fields.addAll(s);
  }
```

Doesn't compile, saying that:

> ```
> addAll
> (java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.String>)
> in Set cannot be applied
> to
> (java.lang.String[])
> ```

is there is a good way to get around this?

Comment: `addAll` takes a collection, not an array. Try `this.fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(s))`

Comment: The data type of **s** varargs is  string array and you want to collect it into hashset.
Thats why you are seeing the exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can convert your array to a list first. Maybe something like

```
this.fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(s));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you further don't want to modify the `Set`, you can use [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of()) with Java-9+ as:

```
public void fields(String... s) {
    this.fields = Set.of(s);
}
```

or else you can use [`Collections.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,T...)) as in:

```
public void fields(String... s) {
    Collections.addAll(fields, s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply convert `array` to `Set` as below code.

```
String [] array = new String[] {"one","two","three","four","five"};
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use google Guava the follow code may help you

```
public void fields(String... s) {
    this.fields.addAll(Sets.newHashSet(s));
}
```

another method:

```
public void fields1(String... s) {
    Sets.union(fields,Sets.newHashSet(s)).copyInto(fields);
}
```